# Gnome Software Center recommended software on the front page is empty

Tags: apt, gnome, software-center

I'm using 18.10. I wonder why Gnome software center does not show recommended software on the starting page. I've tried all the suggestions and answers in other duplicate questions to no avail. I've reinstalled all the gnome-software packages using synaptics. I've tried many ways to remove it and reinstall it, or fix it, such as `sudo apt update`, `sudo apt upgrade`, `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-software`, `killall gnome-software`, `rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-software`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-software`, `sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-software`,
`sudo apt-get install gnome-software`, etc. I've removed canonical and added it back under settings. (It does show my installed software and shows software in the categories however.) Any other ideas?

EDIT (added): I guess it's the editor's picks and recommended software missing.

[image: Empty software center]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. snap service somehow got masked. I had to `sudo systemctl unmask snapd` and `sudo systemctl unmask snapd.socket`, then `sudo systemctl enable snapd`, then `sudo systemctl restart snapd`.